# Termset ID is already present in termstore

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, pnp-powershell, term-set, term

I have a missing term group in my tenant. It's not showing in the admin center where the term store is managed. So I found those very helpful PnP Cmdlets `Export-PnPTermGroupToXml` and `Import-PnPTermGroupFromXml`.

With those I was able to determine that the term group actually still exists in the back-end.

I'm able to export it and the import throws the error:

> Termset ID is already present in termstore.

Is there a way of getting this term group or term set re-imported?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where did you export the termsets? from your current tenant, then re-import it again? The error shows the termset ID has existed.

Comment: Well, I'm doing `Connect-PnPOnline https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/` followed by `Export-PnPTermGroupToXml -Identity "termgroupID`. This exports an xml to my local hard drive. Then I do `Import-PnPTermGroupFromXml -Path "localpath"` and I get the aforementioned error message. To me this means that the term group is still present in the term store but it can't be found though the GUI. Any idea?

Comment: what permission did your account have on your tenant? are you global administrator？

Comment: Yes, I'm the global administrator. Thus far the group 'Company Administrator' was set for the term store but I've also added my own user as well. It shouldn't make a difference as I'm automatically a member of 'Company Administrator' by way of my global administrator role. I verified and the cmdlets still throw the same error. It might try to remove the apparently existing term group but not sure if I should do that. What do you think? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set your account as a **Term Store Administrator** like the below:
[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help. Did that but unfortunately same error. It's kinda logical why the error occurs. I'm exporting a term group from the term store and importing it in the same place. Obviously it already exists. What I just don't get is why I can't see it in the GUI. Actually, executing `Get-PnPTermGroup -TermStore $tenantTermStore.Id | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*TermGroupName" }` shows that there're four term groups with an identical name but different Id's- However, only one contains the term sets I wanted to restore. How can this be?